# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'modules'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, onnx

I'm trying to export a pt file to onnx using the following code:

```
import torch import torchvision

dummy_input = torch.randn(10, 3, 224, 224, device="cuda") model = torch.load('base_40m_textvec.pt')

input_names = [ "actual_input_1" ] + [ "learned_%d" % i for i in range(16) ] output_names = [ "output1" ]

torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "base_40m_textvec.onnx", verbose=True, input_names=input_names, output_names=output_names)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'modules'
```

I tried searching the internet for the error and I got results for

```
object has no attribute 'eval'
object has no attribute 'parameters'
object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

but none for `object has no attribute 'modules'`

This is my first time trying to convert something to onnx, so I don't know why it isn't working. Any help?

Comment: Your code as presented in the question isn't runnable; there are severe formatting problems. Please fix those so that we're able to copy, paste, and run the code locally.

Answer (score 0):

The checkpoint 'base_40m_textvec.pt' you loaded may be an `OrderedDict` instead of a `torch.nn.Module`.

Comment: I am a total novice when it comes to pytorch and onnx so would you mind walking me through how to convert the 'base_40m_textvec.pt' file into an onnx file? Or maybe I could send you the file and you could convert it for me?